# My site is in PHP and its pages are taking more time to open & end with "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"

Tags: php, linux, apache

Pages of my PHP site are taking more time to open & are ending with

**"This webpage is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"** .

This problem started from yesterday. I have checked the error log file and it is saying 
**"mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 120 seconds"** 
**"End of script output before headers: profile.php**".
 Whether I have issues in my code or in server? I am running my site in Linux. Plz help. Thanx.

Comment: That's a `mod_fcgi` specific error and useally doesn't have anything to do with php. The solution would be to increase the timeouts `FcgidIOTimeout` or the old `IPCCommTimeout` found in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf` assuming you have access to this file. Otherwise you'll have to contact your provider about this.

Comment: Thanx @icecub for your reply. Can you please inform me that, this specific "mod_fcgi" error appears when? Because, I am running my site smoothly for last 7-8 months & suddenly this problem raised yesterday.

Comment: Sorry I had to go of to work straight after I made that comment. But I'm afraid I can't answer that question. I simply took the efford of searching the error on Google and finding a solution to it. Something you could've done yourself btw. Members here tend to be more willing to help if you've already put some research efford into your problem yourself.